# Using Sine sample in a loop to per form calculation

Tags: python

I am trying to generate a sine wave and sample it and then take each sample of it and perform calculations using the sample's value, save the calculated value in an array and finally plot the output array against the sine wave. However, I am not able to do this below is my code.

```
def sampled_sine_wave(freq):
    samples = 1000
    time_period = 1
    time = linspace(0,time_period,samples)
    _ = plot(time,[sin(t*freq*2*np.pi) for t in time])

Vin=sampled_sine_wave

if Vin > 0:
    Vpos=Vin
    dw = (1 - numpy.exp(-(1-w)/1))*lamda*((eta1)* numpy.sinh(eta2*Vpos) - (w/tau)) * dt

elif Vin < 0:
    Vneg=Vin
    dw = (1- numpy.exp(-w/0.3))*lamda*((eta1) * numpy.sinh(eta2*Vneg) -   (w/tau)) * dt

current=((1-dw) * alpha *  (1 - numpy.exp(-beta * Vin)) + (dw * gamma *  numpy.sinh(delta * Vin)))
```

So, going back to my explanation I am trying to sample Vin with 0.001s timestep "dt" and at this particular time step I will compare Vin's value greater or less than zero to calculate "dw" and then use this "dw" to calculate "current" and save the calculated current in array to be plotted against its corresponding point/sample from Vin.

So, can anyone help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should import numpy first on the top of the page like this:

```
from numpy import *
```

If you don't have the numpy modul you can download it [here](http://www.scipy.org/scipylib/download.html)